# What is the value of

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{-1}^{1}\max(2-x,2,1+x)dx$

I have no idea how to solve this type of integrals with max function. It would be really helpful if you could explain the min function integration as well.

Comment: at first you must compute $\max(2-x,2,1+x)$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** Draw the function $f(x) = \max (2-x, 2, 1+x)$ in the interval $[-1,1]$. To do this just draw all the functions that are inside the max. Then split the integral according to the picture.

Answer (score 2):

it is $$\int_{-1}^02-xdx+\int_{0}^12dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You have $\int_{-1}^{1}\max(2-x,2,1+x)$

now let's say $f(x)=\max(2-x,2,1+x)=\begin{cases}1+x & \text{if} & ?_1\\2 & \text{if} & ?_2\\2-x & \text{if} & ?_3\end{cases}$

try to find $?_1,?_2,?_3$

after you found those 3 see where each one of them is true over the interval $[-1,1]$  and then split the integral base on what you got

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-1}^{0} 2-x dx+\int_{0}^{1} 2 dx =[2x-\frac{x^2}{2}]^{0}_{-1}+2=\frac{5}{2}+2=\frac{9}{2}.$$